# MongoDB and Robomongo: Can't connect (authentication)

Tags: mongodb

I have the following user:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

And for my database:

```
{
    "_id" : "mydb.mydbDbOwner",
    "user" : "mydbDbOwner",
    "db" : "mydb",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "mydb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't connect via Robomongo on localhost:

[image]

The same goes for...

```
Database: mydb
User Name: root

Database: mydb
User Name: mydbDbOwner
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you enabled authentication in your config file? If not it will only allow localhost access to your database.

Comment: @Tdorno Indeed! `etc/mangodb.conf`auth=true

Comment: What version of MongoDB & Robomongo are you using? If you are using MongoDB 3.0, Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't have support for the new SCRAM-SHA-1 default authentication. See [issue #766](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766) in Robomongo's GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: @Stennie You are correct! Post an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison Are you using mmap (default) or WiredTiger storage engine? There's a possible authentication workaround if you're using mmap.

Comment: @Stennie default. I'm lucky as I'm running localhost I just turned the `Perform authentication` off and connected. This will be an issue for a remote connection though so I hope the patch is released before that!

Comment: Also, if anybody is facing issues deciphering the connection string, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35935789/1578274

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was experiencing exactly the same issue on Mac. I removed the Robomongo client and download the latest version from their website. It just works :)

Answer (score 28):

Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't have support for the new SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication which was the default authentication method added in MongoDB 3.0.

Robomongo 0.9.0 RC4 (Feb 2016) added support for SCRAM-SHA-1, but if you are using a modern version of MongoDB server you should upgrade to the latest version of Robomongo (now Robo3T) currently available.

There is also an officially maintained free GUI, [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), which is more actively updated than Robo3T. MongoDB Compass 1.22+ (Sept 2020) includes an [embedded MongoDB shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/embedded-shell).

Comment: latest version of Robomongo 0.9.0 RC4 supports scram-sha-1 authentication, could you update your answer?

Comment: @AndrewOrsich The answer is still correct (0.8.x doesn't support SCRAM-SHA-1 but this will be part of the 0.9.0 release). I would wait for the final Robomongo 0.9.0 release to know what features are included and link to the actual release announcement.

Comment: How did it go? [The answer can be edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29326527/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today) - e.g. *"... version 0.9.0 of Robomongo (released 2016-XX-XX) added support for SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication."*

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Mongo-Express](https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express) (a web-based tool).

However, you need to upgrade the MongoDB-Node.js library to be at least (1.4.29) according to *[Upgrade to SCRAM](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/)*.

I tried and it worked for my case. You can find the below useful command for that:

> npm install mongo-express
> cd node-modules/mongo-express

Change the *config.default.js* file to *config.js* and update it to include your database connection (e.g., username, password, connection's URL, etc.)

Edit the *package.jon* file and change the version of MongoDB to "~1.4.29"

> Run: npm update

To start the web application: execute command "node app" and the web site will be available at *http://localhost:8081/*.

Answer (score 0):

You can change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to the new version 1.0 of Robomongo. As a few people stated in here, 0.8.x didn’t support SCRAM-SHA-1, which is default in MongoDB 3.0. In prior versions it was MONGODB-CR.

But anyone who is downloading Robomongo from this point on shouldn't have an issue with authentication.

https://robomongo.org/

This bottom links explains SCRAM-SHA a bit more. I suggest reading into it if heavily using MongoDB.

*[SCRAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/)*

Answer (score -1):

Possibility for connection through an SSH tunnel with Robomongo is back in the RC8 version. See GitHub issue *[Where is the SSH tunnel settings on v 0.9.0 RC2 Mac version #1008](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/1008)*.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks