# Unable to connect to remote Mongo Database (v3.0.3)

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, remote-access, robo3t, database

**On the Server**

I have the Mongod instance running on my server.

I created a User on admin, using which I created a user with `readWrite` role on the database that I wanted to access.

Updated the mongo `/etc/mongod.conf` file:

```
commented out the bind ip
uncommented auth=yes
```

Restarted `Mongod` using `sudo service mongod restart`

**On the Client:**

The `db.auth(user,pass)` command works fine on the remote server, but shows auth failure on the client (my home system).

I made sure that I was using the correct database with the `use myDb` command.

PS. I am able to connect to the mongo server using the `mongo xx.xx.xx.xx:27017` command. But unable to Authenticate.

Please help. Mongo v3.0.3.

Comment: You've tagged this with Robomongo .. so I'm guessing that you're trying to use that as the client to authenticate from your home system? If so, lack of support for MongoDB 3.0 auth is a [known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325011/mongodb-robomongo-cant-connect-authentication) with Robomongo 0.8.x.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about Robomongo. But, mongo doesn't even connect in  the client terminal :(

Comment: Can you confirm the specific version of the client you are using? In the `mongo` shell you can get this with `version()`. It would also be helpful if you can include the exact failure message.

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9

Comment: You need to upgrade to a MongoDB 3.x shell. MongoDB 3.0 uses a new authentication method (SCRAM-SHA-1) which isn't supported by older tools or drivers: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/.