# Unable to connect to mongo (3.4) using robomongo (0.9.0) and username and password?

Tags: windows, mongodb, robo3t

I have a mongo 3.4 instance with a cfg file thus:

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: D:\Mongo\log\mongod.log
storage:
 dbPath: D:\Mongo\db
```

Using robomongo version 0.9.0 I've added a user:

[image]
[image]

Now when I try and connect to the DB I get an error:

[image]

I've checked passwords etc all seems correct:

[image]

Without using auth all works as expected.

I've ran though a similar issue [Mongodb & Robomongo: Can't connect (authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325011/mongodb-robomongo-cant-connect-authentication) but because I have a newer version of the client (0.9) which supports SCRAM-SHA-1 this should work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in robobmongo. If I add the user using the console:

```
db.createUser({user:"mongoUser", pwd:"***", roles:["userAdminAnyDatabase"]})
```

Authentication works. But I now get an error from robomongo:

[image]

when I try and expand the list of users in admin.

Comment: You are correct, I am one of the contributors of Robomongo codebase and the user management dialogs do not work as expected. I strongly suggest to use Robomongo shell to add new user or edit not the Robomongo 'Add/Edit User' dialogs.